# Can't get xid of GtkDrawingArea widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, gtk, wayland

I am trying to create a GUI application using python-vlc and Gtk in Python 3.6. But when I try to access the xid of my GtkDrawingArea widget (to bind it with my player's screen), I get an error message

**AttributeError: 'GdkWaylandWindow' object has no attribute 'get_xid'**

Here is the part of code where I'm trying to fetch the xid of GtkDrawingArea widget:

```
def vlc_realize_handler(self, widget, data=None):
    self.win_id = widget.get_property('window').get_xid()
    self.player.set_xwindow(self.win_id)
```

So, how do I bind my player with this widget?

PS - I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 as my Operating System which uses Gnome shell by default.

Comment: It's called xid because it refers to the window's id under the X window system. Wayland is not the X window system, and therefore your windows don't have xids.

Comment: In the login gears icon, choose Ubuntu on Xorg. If you want to try wayland search for Gstreamer wayland sinks.

Comment: Strangely, I am maintaining an old app that uses PyGTK2 and `self.player.set_xwindow(self.window.xid)` works :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused by the fact that Gtk+ 3.0 applications will run through Wayland directly by default. To force the app to go through XWayland (an X Client *over* Wayland), start your app with

```
GDK_BACKEND=x11 your-app
```

I guess this is how many [X11 apps can be used on Wayland](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Wayland_problems#Does_your_application_run_on_Wayland_natively.2C_or_uses_XWayland_.28X11_compatibility_layer.29.3F).